# secondsBetweeenDates return negative value

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, int, nsdate

I'm building an iOS 8 app whereas I got two dates set by the user, for instance (to explain) the start and end time of a cinema movie.

**movieStart:** NSDate time when movie begins playing

**movieEnd:** NSDate time when movie stops playing

I'm using this code to find the difference between the NSDates in seconds and then convert them to hours by dividing it on 3600:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetweeenDates = [self.movieEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:self.movieStart];
float hours = secondsBetweenDates / 3600;
```

**Problem:**

If movieStart is before 12 o'clock and movieEnd is after 12 o'clock, the time returned will be a negative and wrong value, why is this? It works flawless when the time doesn't "pass" 12 o'clock.

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: How are you getting/setting movieStart and movieEnd? Sound like you may be omitting the dates and just keeping the times.

Comment: @LyndseyScott oh I see! I'm using the NSDateFormatter like so: hh:mm:ss and therefore omitting the dates when switching day. Ahh, why didn't I think of that...